# Alternative to setting variables in SELECT for MySQL 8

Tags: mysql

I have a context where I need to be able to run the same query under MySQL 5 and 8. When running the following SQL query:

```sql
SET
    @item_row := 0,
    @var_row := 0;
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            @item_row := @item_row + 1 AS `row_nr`,
            `id` AS `order_item_id`
        FROM
            `order_items`
        WHERE
            `order_id` = ?
    ) `items`
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            @var_row := @var_row + 1 AS `row_nr`,
            `index_number`
        FROM
            `recipe_variables`
        WHERE
            `recipe_variables`.`order_id` = ?
            AND `recipe_variables`.`index_number` = 1
    ) `vars` USING (`row_nr`)
    INNER JOIN `order_items`
    ON `order_items`.`id` = `items`.`order_item_id`
WHERE
    `items`.`order_item_id` = ?
```

I get the following warning:

```
setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
```

And the results are incorrect. However only under one environment running MySQL 8. On another server running MySQL 8 it works fine, and on yet another running MySQL 5, it too works correctly without warnings.

I know I can rewrite the query to not use variables by using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` instead, but this is not supported on the old MySQL 5 server that I am not allowed the update for the moment.

I checked their full versions and both MySQL 8 databases return `8.0.25` (using `SELECT VERSION()`). What can cause this difference? And how can I change my query such that is still backwards compatible with MySQL 5, but does run without warnings under MySQL 8?

Comment: Have you tried to set the variables like `@item_row := @item_row + 1 as row_nr` instead of `(SELECT @item_row + 1 INTO @item_row) AS row_nr`?

Comment: Ah, whoops, I meant to have written `@item_row := @item_row + 1 as row_nr`. I copied over my test case where I tried using `INTO` as suggested by the warning. Unfortunately it is not allowed to have a `SELECT ... INTO` query as a subquery, so that test failed.

Comment: The variable should work in both versions. As the message says, it's deprecated, but not yet removed. In what way are the results incorrect? Can you post sample data and the results in each version?

Comment: You have no `ORDER BY` in either of your subqueries that uses the variables, so the order that the numbers are assigned is unpredictable. There's no reason to expect that to be consistent across versions.

Comment: How did you check the versions? You should use `SELECT VERSION();` to get the version of the MySQL Server. Whatever you did may have returned the version of the client you use.

Comment: The solutions which would allow the query to work on both versions of MySQL without issuing warnings would require you to change the tables. For example, instead of calculating row numbers dynamically, you could add a column and store values by which you join the tables.

Comment: The solution that does not require changing the tables would be to run one query or the other conditionally. This would require some logic in application code, to check the MySQL Server version, and then branch with an `if/then/else` statement to run different queries depending on the version.

Comment: @BillKarwin I could probably work around using variables by using a temporary table, but as the warnings only occur in my test environment and not live, I am OK with it for now until I can move everything over to MySQL 8 and just use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The key mistake was using `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` in the presence of counter variables, which caused the `row_nr` to always resolve to 1, due the filter always resulting in at most 1 record (unique identifier). Apparently the semantics of MySQL 5 and 8 differs in this regard, as version 5 behaves the same whether you use `WHERE` or `HAVING`.

Using `HAVING` it now works consistently across environments, except for the warnings only still showing up in the one, but that suffices for my needs. The best solution is to just upgrade that old MySQL 5 server and rewriting the query to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()`, which will happen in a few months, so I can live with a few warnings for now.

I did add `ORDER BY` clauses as suggested by @Barmar, as though it returns the records in insertion order in practice, I don't actually have this guarantee according to the semantics of MySQL, so better to just add them to be sure (`ORDER BY id ASC`). I also added a `LIMIT` as otherwise the `ORDER BY` does not need to be adhered to according to the semantics, as I have run into when wanting to [group by an ordered subquery in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/).